# :How can I change this Python code to use map ,filter, and reduce so that it can produce result with as few code possible?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a Python code and I am trying to reduce the lines of code possible using Python Functional Porgramming:

```
for t in text_from_file:
    separated_text = separate_data(t)
    employees.append(Employee(separated_text[1], separated_text[3], separated_text[7], float(separated_text[8])))

for e in employees:
    if e.hire_type == "FullTime":
        e.monthly_payout = e.salary
    elif e.hire_type == "Hourly":
        e.monthly_payout = e.salary * 0.5
    else:
        e.monthly_payout = e.salary * 0.25

    


for e in employees:
    year = datetime.strptime(e.start_date, '%d/%m/%Y').year
    if year > 1995:
        e.monthly_payout = e.monthly_payout * 0.85
        print(f"{e.full_name:<12} | Monthly payout | {e.monthly_payout:<8}")
        print("____________________________________")
```

How do I convert these codes using lambda, map, filter, and reduce?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for with the lambdas.  But you can reduce your currenct example by doing everything in one loop instead of looping over the same thing 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming (FP) doesn't necessarily make your program shorter, and you don't necessarily need to use functions like `map`, `lambda` etc. I'd suggest that writing FP-style in a language like Python is more about structuring your code (usually by modularity, e.g. helper functions) so that you can more easily reason about types, side-effects, and correctness.

For example, you could rewrite your first loop as (in Python3 with type annotations):

```py
def update_payout(e: Employee, default: float = 0.25) -> Employee:
    """Update employee monthly payout based on hire type."""
    if e.hire_type == "FullTime":
        e.monthly_payout = e.salary
    elif e.hire_type == "Hourly":
        e.monthly_payout = e.salary * 0.5
    else:
        e.monthly_payout = e.salary * default
    return e

employees = [update_payout(e) for e in employees]
```

Note that a `default` multipler argument was added, because the function can now be reused in your second loop. For your second loop, you can write another list comprehension, and separate the IO activity of printing.

```py
emloyees_ = [update_payout(e, 0.85) for e in employees if 
             datetime.strptime(e.start_date, '%d/%m/%Y').year > 1995]

for e in employees_:
    print('your printing function...')
```

Or you could rewrite the second loop with a helper function too, and run just one list comprehension, like so:

```py
employees = [update_post_1995(update_payout(e)) for e in employees]
```

Chaining functions is very functional, but note that in Python the syntax makes it a bit harder to read, and you really want to use type checking with e.g. `mypy` if you do so.